# Date format corrupted in sub fields when copying an ACF field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I've created a CPT to store a show calendar.
An ACF field `calendar` has been created to store places and dates of the shows. It is a repeater composed by 2 subfields: `date` (type=date) and `city` (type=select).

When I'm trying to copy the "calendar" field from one post to another, using
`update_field( 'calendar', get_field( 'calendar', $id_post_origin ), $id_post_destination );`
the dates are corrupted.

I've tried to run a `delete_field()` before but the result isn't better.

e.g. if my original post is:
`0 => 
  array (size=2) 
    'city' => string 'Vesoul' (length=6) 
    'date' => string '02/09/2019' (length=10)`
the destination post will be after copying:
`0 => 
  array (size=2) 
    'city' => string 'Vesoul' (length=6) 
    'date' => string '09/02/2019' (length=10)`

Is it possible to specify a date format? To duplicate a field without modifying it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As specified by Kenny from ACF support,

> The get_field() function contains a formatting parameter that you set to false in order to return the raw database value. In the case of the date field, the unformated string would be in YYYYMMD format.

The ACF [get_field() manual](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) describes this `$format_value` parameter and provide an example to "Get a value without formatting".

In my case, the solution was to edit the `get_field()` call like this:
`$dates = get_field( 'calendar', $id_post_origin, false ); // false to retrieve raw data
update_field( 'calendar', $dates, $id_post_destination );`

Comment: Was having a ton of issues with the date, but adding false resolved my issues.  thanks!